# How can I change the SQL batch separator used by Visual Studio's Intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

As per image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m58oa.png) below, I am getting Intellisense warnings in a SQL file that is contained in my codebase. These warnings result from the use of a custom batch separator, instead of the default `GO` keyword - if I change these to `GO` then the warnings disappear. I want to be able to change the batch separator that Visual Studio uses to analyse warnings in SQL files, how can I do that?

In image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUtdq.png) I show how I would change this setting in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), but I cannot find an equivalent setting despite similar Options pages in Visual Studio (image [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGiue.png)).

NB: The reason for using a custom batch separator is so that we can do a string split on a keyword that is more rare than "GO" in the data. Not ideal but works well enough for constructing out testing database.

**Image 1** - Intellisense warning `SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near '@BATCHSEP@'`:

[image: SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near '@BATCHSEP@']

**Image 2** - Set batch separator in SSMS:

[image: Set batch separator in SSMS]

**Image 3** - Similar settings in Visual Studio:

[image: Similar settings in Visual Studio]

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and Visual Studio are two different types of MS products. Therefore the settings menu under Tools-option is different. I’m afraid there’s no similar Options `Batch separator` in Visual Studio.

You may access this URL: [suggest](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest) to submit any comments and feature request for future releases and implementations.

But I find this doc :[sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax) that provides command to change SQL Batch separator   in Visual Studio. I tested this command in my sqlcmd but it seems fails with no error and no output, just returns silently. There may be some problems with my environment.

For example

```
sqlcmd  -S (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB  -c @BATCHSEP@
```

RESULT

[image]

Maybe you can try this workaround and see if it works for your environment.

Then enable SQLCMD Mode under SQL->Execution Settings->SQLCMD Mode.

[image: SQLCMD Mode]

After setting this, Intellisense will not  show warning `SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near '@BATCHSEP@'`